# How to publish Jmeter results into PowerBI (dashboard)?

Tags: jmeter, powerbi, dashboard, resultset, powerbi-desktop

Has anybody know how to see the results from Jmeter in PowerBI? How to configure the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [.jtl results files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) are basically [CSV files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) so if you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/script.jmx -l /path/to/result.csv
```

you should be able to [import this `result.csv` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-comma-separated-value-files) into PowerBI via `Files -> Get data` menu entry